# Can we get a tight lower bound of the minimum of several i.i.d. random variables satisfying these conditions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

I am stuck by the following problem. Could you please help me? Million thanks.

We have $c$ non-negative, i.i.d. random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_c >0$, where $\mathbb{E}[X_i]\geq\lambda>0$, and $X_i-\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ is sub-gaussian with variance $V_i\leq \beta^2$, $\forall i\in[c]= \{1,2,...,c\}$.

Now consider $Y=\min_{i\in[c]} X_i$, I want to prove a lower bound on $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[Y]\geq f(\lambda,c,\beta)>0$, where $f(\lambda,c,\beta)$ is a positive quantity that depends on $\lambda$, $c$ and $\beta$.

Below is what I have tried.

From the property of sub-gaussian random variables:

$P(X_i-\mathbb{E}[X_i]<-a)\leq e^{-\frac{a^2}{2\beta^2}}$, $\forall a>0$.

Therefore, for a fixed $i$:

$P(X_i\geq\lambda-a)\geq 1-e^{-\frac{a^2}{2\beta^2}}$.

Thus,

$P(\min_{i\in [c]}X_i>\lambda-a)\geq (1-e^{-\frac{a^2}{2\beta^2}})^c$.

So we have

$\mathbb{E}[Y]\geq\lambda_2=\int_{0}^{\lambda}(1-e^{-\frac{(\lambda-x)^2}{2\beta^2}})^c dx$.

I am wondering if it is possible to get a better result, or if it is possible to simplify this to get rid of the integration. Could you please kindly help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You know $X_i \geq 0$ and $E(X_i )>0$ therefore, $E[\min X_i]>0$

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{E}[min X_i]>0$. But I want to get a tighter lower bound of $\mathbb{E}[min X_i]$, which can be quantified by $c,\lambda, \beta$. Could you please help me with that? Thanks.